# CakePHP Hash::diff works not properly

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I want to send to my view 2 arrays - second one shouldn't have elements from the first one. I used Hash::diff but it doesn't work great with CakePHP arrays.

```
    $edited = $this->Instrument->find('all', array(
         'conditions'=>array(
            'status' => '1'),
        'fields' => array('Instrument.id',[and other fields]),
         'order'=> array('modified'=>'desc'),
         'limit'=>100
     ));


    $new = $this->Instrument->find('all', array(
         'conditions'=>array(
            'status' => '1'),
        'fields' => array('Instrument.id', [and other fields]),
         'order'=> array('added'=>'desc'),
         'limit'=>5
     ));


 $this->set(array(
     'edytowane'=>Hash::diff($edited, $new),
     'nowe'=>$new
 ));
```

But after that I sometimes have few the same records in `$edytowane` as in `$new` variable. What do I wrong ? :)

Comment: You need to show what `$edited` and `$new` are - and what the result of `Hash::diff($edited, $new)` is, _and_ what you're expecting it to be. It's not really important where those variables come from. That said I don't expect what you're doing to work - it's the same data sorted in a different order, `Hash::diff` isn't for removing duplicates or something.

Comment: So the best way to remove duplicates will be writing an own method to do it?

Comment: I doubt it - why don't you pass the ids from `$edited` into the condition for new? It would be better to describe what you want to do (with enough info to answer it) rather than pursue [a flawed solution](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

I have done it like that - it's rather a bit not efficient, but works fine for me:

```
$ids_nowych = array();   

$new = $this->Instrument->find('all', array(
         'conditions'=>array(
            'status' => '1'),
        'fields' => array('Instrument.id',[and other fields]),
         'order'=> array('added'=>'desc'),
         'limit'=>5
     ));


foreach ($new as $n){
        $ids_nowych[] = $n['Instrument']['id']; 
}


    $edited = $this->Instrument->find('all', array(
         'conditions'=>array(
            'status' => '1',
            'NOT' => array(
                'Instrument.id' => $ids_nowych
            )),
        'fields' => array('Instrument.id',[and other fields]),
         'order'=> array('modified'=>'desc'),
         'limit'=>100
     ));




 $this->set(array(
     'edytowane'=>$edited,
     'nowe'=>$new
 ));
```